# Getting original layout of view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a quick question which I have struggle to find an answer to - I have a view controller which has a lot of changes to the positioning of some of its elements (changing alpha, transforming, moving etc), but at one point I need everything go back to how it was in the beginning with the original UI layout. I guess this means reloading the view controller, but I am unsure how. Is anyone able to suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Need to more information but try smth: `self.view = nil; [self loadView]` in your UIViewController.